# How to create different subclass of an object based on "if" condition

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 2 UITableViews in one Controller. Each table have its own cell prototypes with different subclasses of UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if(tableView == self.commentsTable){
        CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];        
        cell.message.text = @"test";
    }else if(tableView == self.paramsTableView){
        RealtyParamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RealtyParamCell"];
        cell.label.text = @"test2";        
    }

    return cell;
}
```

If I do it this way, I'm getting an error on last line `return cell;`: **"Use of undefined identifier cell"** But I can't define `cell` in the beginning:

```
UItableViewCell *cell;
if(tableView == self.commentsTable){
  <...>
}
```

because I need exact class for cell - `CommentCell` or `RealtyParamCell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if(tableView == self.commentsTable){
        CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];        
        cell.message.text = @"test";
        return cell;
    }else if(tableView == self.paramsTableView){
        RealtyParamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RealtyParamCell"];
        cell.label.text = @"test2";
        return cell;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried it and this also doesn't work - Xcode says that there must be "return" at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method - outside of "if" condition.

Comment: you missing `else return nil;`

Comment: @BryanChen - `else return nil` is the thing I missed, thanks! Now it works.

Answer (score 5):

well, you still can define `cell` at beginning

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UItableViewCell *cell;
    if(tableView == self.commentsTable){
        CommentCell *commentCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];        
        commentCell.message.text = @"test";
        cell = commentCell;
    }else if(tableView == self.paramsTableView){
        RealtyParamCell *realtyParamCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RealtyParamCell"];
        realtyParamCell.label.text = @"test2";        
        cell = realtyParamCell;
    }

    return cell;
```

Comment: I think it is appropriate to add to this answer that you can do that because the class which the object really has is the class you have created the object with, and it doesn't change even if you store it as a pointer with other class.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment to be honest, but you can do it because they are subclasses of `UITableViewCell`.